# Is there a probability density function of unbounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, bounded-variation

I know that a function of bounded variation is integrable. Can an integrable function be of unbounded variation?

Comment: Any continuous function on a bounded set is integrable. There are a lot of continuous functions with unbounded variations, e.g. most of sample paths of Brownian motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What  about
$$\sin\frac1x$$
on $[0,1]$?

Comment: And if you insist on a "probability density function" use $a (1+\sin\frac{1}{x})$ on $0 < x < 1$ for an appropriate constant $a$.